# elasticsearch scan all object fields

Tags: elasticsearch

For following object:

```
{
  name: 'value1',
  name$en_US: 'value2',
  name$fr_CA: 'value3',
  ...
  ...
}
```

**And my query:**
`

```
"query": {
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "and": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "product"
          }
        },
        {
          "or": [
            {
              "regexp": {
                "name": ".*sometext.*"
              }
            },
            {
              "regexp": {
                "name$en_US": ".*sometext.*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

`
**My Mappings for different possible locales**:

```
NAME: {
    type: "string",
    index: "not_analyzed",
    doc_values: true,
    fielddata: {
        format: "doc_values"
    },
    fields: {
    ft: {
            type: "string",
            analyzer: "standard",
            ignore_above: 10922
        }
    },
    ignore_above: 10922
},
NAME$en_CN: {
    type: "string",
    index: "no",
    ignore_above: 10922
},
NAME$en_US: {
    type: "string",
    index: "no",
    ignore_above: 10922
},
NAME$es_US: {
    type: "string",
    index: "no",
    ignore_above: 10922
},
```

I have an issue that ElasticSearch works well with **name** but in fails on name with locale. How can I fix it ?

Added query and mappings.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Please, provide more information as it is not clear.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I mean response.hits.hits is empty array

Comment: What's the query?

Comment: @AndreiStefan added to question description

Comment: Can you also share the mapping of `name$en_US` field and a document that should match and it doesn't? Also, `sometext` should probably have a real value you're using in your search.

Comment: @AndreiStefan added mappings and as for text - product name is "Showcase® Interior Paint & Primer" and I use regexp to be able to search by a part: "Interior Paint"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `name$en_US` and the other language-specific fields have `index: "no"` which makes it not searchable.

If the field's content is not indexed then it's not possible to search on it. Snippet from [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/mapping-index.html):

> The `index` option controls whether field values are indexed. It accepts `true` or `false`. **Fields that are not indexed are not queryable**.